# How can I find hidden items in Automator?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, macos, automator

I am trying to create a workflow in Automator that will find hidden files in a folder by searching for files with names that begin with ".".
Currently, the `Find FInder Items` action is as follows:

```
Find Finder Items
    Search: [(Var:Selection path)]
        [All] of the following are true
            [Name] [begins with] "."
```

[image: a screenshot of the action]

Here is the log showing the error:
[image: action log]

It does not receive any input, but outputs to a `Move Finder Items` action. Every time this action is run, it produces no results. Am I doing this wrong, or is there another way to find hidden files and folders in a variable path? I do not know much about other scripting languages such as applescript, but I am willing to use them if necessary. *Thanks for reading!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Run Shell Script action like this:

```
find "$@" -name .\*
```

Comment: Disregard that previous comment. I forgot to get the variable before running the script. Thank you very much!